# ¿Cual es la diferencia de usar entity data model y la plantilla POCO?

Tags: c#, .net, orm

Quisiera saber cuaĺ es la diferencia y que es mejor si usar la plantilla de Entity Data Model para generar el modelo de la base de datos o utilizar la plantilla POCO Reverse Generator, al igual si es mejor instalar las dependencia de entity framework desde el nuget package manager o utilizar la que viene por defecto en visual studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La diferencia entre las dos modelados es la siguiente:

Con **Entity Data Model** tienes la base de datos como inicio, basando en esa base de datos se generan las entidades y relaciones con un tratamiento "Data Base First". *Este caso es Data Base First usando tu base de datos original.*

Con **POCO Reverse Generator** también partes de la base de datos, el siguiente paso es que se generan clases POCO replicando los modelos de la base de datos y al final esas clases POCO mediante Code First recrean la base de datos. *Este caso es Code First usando clases creadas mediante ingeniería inversa a tu base de datos.*

En cuanto a la dependencia de Entity Framework que viene por defecto ya viene pre configurada pero generalmente es una versión anterior a la que puedes encontrar en NuGet. Esta versión puede ser actualizada a la última por lo que no representa mayor problema.